# Tuning Jackrabbit data model (VERSION_BUNDLE table)

Tags: java, oracle, jackrabbit, jcr

As part of our application, we are using Jackrabbit (1.6.4) to store documents. Each document that is retrieved by our application is put into a folder structure in Jackrabbit, which is created if not existing.

Our DBA has noticed that the following query is executed a lot against the Oracle (11.2.0.2.0) database holding the Jackrabbit schema - more than 50000 times per hour, causing a lot of IO on the database. In fact, it is one of the top 5 SQL statements in terms of IO over elapsed time (97% IO):

```
    select BUNDLE_DATA from VERSION_BUNDLE where NODE_ID = :1
```

Taking a look at the database, one notices that this table initially only contains a single record, comprising the `node_id` (data type RAW) key with the `DEADBEEFFACEBABECAFEBABECAFEBABE` value and then a couple of bytes in the `bundle_data` BLOB column. Later on, more records are added with additional data.

The SQL for the table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "VERSION_BUNDLE"
(    
    "NODE_ID" RAW(16) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "BUNDLE_DATA" BLOB NOT NULL ENABLE
);
```

I have the following questions:

- Why is Jackrabbit accessing this table so frequently?
- Any Jackrabbit tuning options to make this faster?
- Is the `BUNDLE_DATA` value changed by Jackrabbit at all or is it just read for every access to the repository?
- Is there any way to tune the database schema to make it deal better with this scenario?

*Update: The table only initially contains one record, additional records are added over time as decided internally by Jackrabbit. The access still seems to be read-only for most of the cases, as insert or update statements are not reported as being run with a high number.*

Comment: Hi @nwinkler, did you understand this issue? We are experiencing same problem, thanks

Comment: Sorry, it's been more than six years since I asked this question - I don't remember what we did to fix this...

Comment: Thank you, could you point me to someone who can remember? It would be much important for me to know more about this issue, if you can I give you my mail address r.gambelli@hitachi-systems-cbt.com

Answer (score 2):

Is this physical i/o or logical? With the data being read that often I'd be surprised if the blocks are being aged out of the cache fast enough for physical i/o to be required.

Comment: I'm not a DBA, but I would guess that it's logical IO. The AWR report shows the statement under the "SQL ordered by User I/O Wait Time", but not under the "SQL ordered by Reads".

Comment: One way of clearing that up is to look at the v$segment_statistics view, which will break out the logical and physical i/o for the table and any associated indexes. You can then compare with other segments to see whether it is truly a significant level of i/o across the entire system

Answer (score 1):

> Why is Jackrabbit accessing this table so frequently?

Then it's a sign that you're creating versions in your repository. Is that something which your application is supposed to do?

> Any Jackrabbit tuning options to make this faster?

Not that I'm aware of ; one option to investigate is to upgrade to a more recent Jackrabbit version. [Version 2.4.2](http://www.apache.org/dist/jackrabbit/2.4.2/RELEASE-NOTES.txt) was just released and 1.6.4 is almost two years old. It's a possibility that there were performance improvements between these releases.

> Is the BUNDLE_DATA value changed by Jackrabbit at all or is it just read for every access to the repository?

By the looks of it's the GUID of the root repository node.

> Is there any way to tune the database schema to make it deal better with this scenario?

As far as I know the schema is auto-generated by Jackrabbit so the only options are to modify the table definition in a compatible way after it's been created. But that's a topic for a DBA, which I am not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Updating to 2.x is currently not an option. I have updated my question, the table contains more than one record - initially there's only the root node, but then other records are added over time. This still doesn't explain why this table is accessed so frequently and why the access takes so much time.

Comment: @nwinkler Then it's a sign that you're creating versions in your repository. Is that something which your application is supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, we are using versioning as part of the application. So the records in the VERSION_BUNDLE make sense. We are currently digging through the application code to see where the application could be accessing Jackrabbit in a pattern like we're seeing on the DB. The amount of queries against Jackrabbit is off by a magnitude (or close to that) from what we would expect.

Answer (score 1):

If the JCR-Store is based within a Oracle database you could reorganize the underlying table.

1. Build a [hash-cluster](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/hash003.htm) of that table to prevent index accesses
2. Check if you've licenses to use [partitioning option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/partconc.htm)
3. By deleting unnecessary versions in your application rows will got deleted (Version prune)

If you're storing binary objects like pictures, documents - just have also a look at VERSION_BINVAL.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is Jackrabbit accessing this table so frequently?

We have seen that this table is accessed very often even if you are not asking for versions.
Take a look [to this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jackrabbit-users/201812.mbox/%3cOF738F8905.72CC8783-ONC1258359.004AE815-C1258359.004BA3CA@hitachi-systems-cbt.com%3e) from Jackrabbit users mailing list